# Is concatAll the right RxJS operator in order to preserve order?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have the following **rxjs** observable chain:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.map(params => params['userAccountToken'])
      .switchMap(userAccountToken => this.userAccountService.activateAccount(userAccountToken))
      .switchMap(() => this.route.params.map(params => params['userAccountToken']))
      .switchMap(userAccountToken => this.signinService.signinByUserAccountToken(userAccountToken))
      .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']));
  }
```

FYI, `route` is of type: `ActivatedRoute`.

The issue is that I am trying to reuse the following observable:

```
route.params.map(params => params['userAccountToken'])
```

Notice how I duplicate this observable: first in order to activate the account and then to signin the user...

I am trying to find a way to reuse the value of the token but I am not sure which operator to use.

The order of the calls needs to be preserved. Is `concatAll` appropriate here?

See below for another attempt:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.map(params => params['userAccountToken'])
      .mergeMap(userAccountToken => Observable.concatAll(
        this.userAccountService.activateAccount(userAccountToken),
        this.sessionService.signinByUserAccountToken(userAccountToken)
      ))
      .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']));
  }
```

Also, do I need to `mergeMap` or `switchMap` on the `route.param.map...`?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the docs yet? - http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatAll

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have indeed looked at the docs but I am unsure which operator to choose given my use case.

Comment: But you probably haven't tried it out yet, correct? Because `concatAll` is an operator and not an Observable-creator, so `Observable.concatAll(...)` should throw an error `is not a function`.

Comment: Yes. I haven't tried it yet. Do you mean `concatAll` is an instance operator and not a factory method?

Comment: Correct, that's also what it says in the docs

Answer (score 2):

You could e.g. nest two switchMaps:

```
this.route.params
    .take(1)
    .pluck('userAccountToken')
    .switchMap(userAccountToken => {
        return this.userAccountService.activateAccount(userAccountToken)
            .switchMapTo(this.signinService.signinByUserAccountToken(userAccountToken))
    })
    .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']));
```

Comment: Thanks olsn. Could you please explain a little your code? Especially the necessity for the `take(1)`?

Comment: the `take(1)` is just to prevent memory-leaks, since `route.params` is a continuous stream it will keep emitting data even after the component is removed, which will cause memory leaks - as an alternative you could keep a reference to the subscription and unsubscribe on destroy or use a pattern with `takeUntil(someTriggerWhenDestroyingTheComponent)` - the `take(1)` is just the quickest way to ensure no memory leaks happen